# How to get value of TextField Attribute in Magento 2 in .phtml?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.2

I have created "Text Field" Attribute and configured "Yes" in "Used in Product Listing". while I am trying to retrieving value of this text field using below code it is giving me blank output.

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getTestAttribute() ?>
```

[image]

Still not able to get value of this attribute in my `product/list.phtml` file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the list page you can use $_product object, whats you code, please add here.

Comment: I have already written the code in question. For testing purpose my attribute name is "TestAttribute" . So, I have used below code in my .phtml
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_product->getTestAttribute() ?>

Comment: Try getData() , getAttributeText() functions. "<?= " is it support short tags

Comment: Yes, it is supporting "<?=" short tags. I am using this for other attributes.
in $_product->getData() output I am not able to find my "TestAttribute" .
I think, this is the reason I am not able to get value of it. Ideally it should be there in product attribute.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_getMyAttr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute');
```

// Get Value

```
$attrTestValue = $_getMyAttr->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

// Get Label

```
$attrTestLabel = $_getMyAttr->getStoreLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check values are there in admin product section. if the values are present, it will display on frontend.

Comment: Yes, I have checked value is there in admin product section.